# Can you precompute C++ code ahead of run time?

Tags: c++

I was looking through a competitive programming problem solution and I found a brute force solution that precomputes words in a solution. This solution is in Python.
Problem Statement: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1205
Source: http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_prob3_bronze_feb22.html

```
def solve():
    n = int(input())
    l = [input() for _ in range(4)]
    words = set()
    for a in range(4):
        for b in range(4):
            if a in [b]:
                continue
            for c in range(4):
                if c in [a, b]:
                    continue
                for d in range(4):
                    if d in [a, b, c]:
                        continue
                    for l1 in l[a]:
                        words.add(l1)
                        for l2 in l[b]:
                            words.add(l1+l2)
                            for l3 in l[c]:
                                words.add(l1+l2+l3)
                                for l4 in l[d]:
                                    words.add(l1+l2+l3+l4)
    for _ in range(n):
        print("YES" if input() in words else "NO")
 
solve()
```

This is just a word generator. Since this list of words would be massive when run, I was wondering whether there is anyway to compute C++ code ahead of time(perhaps during compiling?) so that the program can run more efficiently during runtime. I am an absolute beginner at C++ and wording this question was a little difficult for me, please ask if you need me to clarify more. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's called `constexpr` - or you could C-style preprocessor macros - or you could abuse  C++s `template<>` (as they're Turing-complete). Personally I'd just use T4 though if your IDE supports it.

Comment: Depending on how large the precomputed thing is, you can just hardcode it.

Comment: As far as I understand you get the input (letters) only at runtime?

Comment: What do you want to precompute for this function?

Comment: Let me clarify a little bit. 
@Sebastian For this problem, yes, I only get the input at runtime. In this question, I was asking just in general how I could pre-generate stuff. Instead of generating a list in for example O(N^2) during runtime, I could do that in compiling, thus improving the performance of my program.

Comment: With constexpr functions you could probably do the complete calculation at compile-time, if the input is available then